# MS SQL double group by

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by

I have a table 'Hobbys' with two columns. It looks like this:

```
NAME   | HOBBY
Alice  | sport
Bob    | painting
...    | ...
Yves   | programming
Zooey  | theatre
```

Rows could be duplicated. For example 'Bob' with hobby 'painting' can appear twice, thrice or even more times. 
I want find that people, who have more than one hobby. I tried to use query like this one:

```
select NAME, HOBBY
from Hobbys
group by NAME, HOBBY
order by 1, 2
```

But I don't know how to use the query result for second grouping by NAME.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want find that people, who have more than one hobby.

In my opinion the easiest is using `EXISTS`

```
SELECT NAME,HOBBY FROM dbo.Hobbys h1
WHERE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 1 FROM dbo.Hobbys h2
    WHERE h1.Name = h2.Name AND h1.HOBBY <> h2.HOBBY
)
```

Answer (score 3):

To find the users with more than one hobby, just group by the name and count the distinct hobbies;

```
SELECT name 
FROM hobbies
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT hobby)>1
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16502/1).

If you want the users *and* their hobbies, you can use a CTE;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT name FROM hobbies GROUP BY name HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT hobby)>1
)
SELECT * FROM hobbies JOIN cte ON hobbies.name = cte.name
```

[Another SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/16502/4).

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
SELECT NAME,HOBBY
FROM Hobbys
GROUP BY NAME
HAVING COUNT(HOBBY) > 1
```